# How to convert a pixel art gif into an HD mp4?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, video-conversion, gif, twitter

I'm a pixel animator on twitter, with a problem...  The website only hosts video files, and will automatically convert `gifs` into aggressively compressed `mp4` files that are 10kb big, destroying the art.

However, twitter allows one to upload fairly high-definition video files if you provide the `mp4` yourself.

It's a weird situation, but to overcome this limitation, I want to try converting my 60kb 135x150 pixel `gif`, into a perceptually lossless 720x720 pixel 2048kb bitrate `mp4`.  I'm very unfamiliar with video formats, I've gleaned these stats from this [twitter API doc](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/media/upload-media/uploading-media/media-best-practices).  But size is no object, I'm happy to make the video unconscionably large for twitter.

Is there a way I can ask `ffmpeg` to perform this crime?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Upscaling from 135x150 to 720x720 is not going to be "perceptually lossless".

Comment: @Rotem - is that an artifact of the video format, or maybe our definitions differ?  In my view, upscaling in integer increments with no interpolation, is "lossless."  I can perform cropping on the input gif to make it so it's 144x144 to facilitate that.

Comment: The duplicate has a lot of options, and https://superuser.com/search?q=ffmpeg+resize can show you how to resize using ffmpeg. What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @Mokubai - most gif2mp4 commands I've found reduce filesize instead of sacrifice it.  I suppose I should research video formats, instead of looking for ffmpeg commands specifically, maybe a better understanding will let me figure out the command I'd need.

Comment: You may be upscaling in integer increments, but the video codecs themselves do not honour pixel boundaries. The first stages of ffmpeg converting the frame resolution up *might* be lossless, but the moment the data is passed to a video encoder there will be block filtering, psychovisual approximations and a lot of processing that is far from lossless. It might seem *visually* near lossless, but modern video formats are anything but lossless.

Comment: @AnneQuinn check the rest of the answers in the duplicate, ffmpeg is in there as well. Pick a format, try options, tell us what does and does not work. Help us to help you.